# Good directory jumper for Powershell?

Tags: powershell, command-line

I just heard about [the (almost impossible to google) z directory jumper for bash](https://github.com/rupa/z/)

Does anyone know of a powershell equivalent, or anything that even approaches the functionality?

Comment: @Andy Arismendi gives [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9899997/608772) an ineresting function which complete Set-Location, Get-Location, Pop-Location and Push-Location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PowerShell there is [Jump-Location](https://github.com/tkellogg/Jump-Location) and [Z](https://github.com/vincpa/z). You might also want to check out [Go](https://github.com/cameronharp/Go-Shell).

Comment: I'm currently using Z and it's pretty solid

Answer (score 4):

I had written [`cdposh`](https://github.com/manojlds/cdposh) and [`poshmarks`](https://github.com/manojlds/poshmarks) which might be useful for you.

`cdposh` lets you specify environment variable `cdpath` and lets you switch directly to a directory on the cdpath (much like path for executables)

`poshmarks` lets you bookmark and quickly go to directories.

I will see if I can implement `z` for Powershell

**Update**: A very early implementation of `z` for Powershell - [`posz`](https://github.com/manojlds/posz)

Answer (score 1):

The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) has a nested module that will override your CD function and then provide you with a history list of dirs you've navigated to.  To can move forwards and backwards through this list or jump to a particular entry e.g.:

```
6# cd

     # Directory Stack:
   --- ----------------
     0 C:\Users\hillr
     1 C:\Temp
     2 C:\Windows
->   3 C:\Windows\System32

7# cd -
C:\Windows
8# cd +
C:\Windows\System32
9# cd -1
C:\Temp
```

It's not quite as fancy as frequency based directory jumper but it is surprisingly handy.